# Sum narray to every matrix rows, element by elemnt

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix

this is my first post here so please forgive me for any mistake.

This is an example:

My matrix:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

My narray:

```
[20, 0, 10, 5]
```

Would like to get:

```
[[20, 0, 10, 5],
 [21, 1, 11, 6],
 [22, 3, 14, 10],
 [26, 7, 18, 14]]
```

Which is the best way to do it?

Thatk you very much

Comment: Well, if you'd simply tried `x + y`, you'd have noticed it gives you what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use simple `+` operator, numpy will do auto-broadcasting for you.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1],[2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9]])
b = np.array([20,0,10,5])

print(a+b)

# [[20  0 10  5]
# [21  1 11  6]
# [22  3 14 10]
# [26  7 18 14]]
```